# Uploading an image to a CloudDeploy Wolfram Language web app

Tags: wolfram-cloud, web-access, webservices

I want to do image processing using the Wolfram Language on a web app hosted on the Wolfram Cloud.

The user must be able to upload a PNG image to the Wolfram Cloud, how can I set  this up?

I've been looking at the documentation of [CloudDeploy](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudDeploy.html) and haven't found something related yet. Should I be looking instead at the [Wolfram Data Drop and its REST interface](https://www.wolfram.com/datadrop/quick-reference/web-api/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`CloudDeploy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudDeploy.html) is not the whole story. [`FormPage`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormPage.html) or [`FormFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FormFunction.html) will give you access to file system and even camera on a mobile device. Simplest example:

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage[{"image" -> "Image"}, EdgeDetect[#image] &],
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

[image]

There is a very nice example [HERE](https://www.imageidentify.com/about/how-it-works):

[image]

Comment: How do you do that with multiple images (= list of images) at once?

Comment: @Detlef Did you ever learn how to do this with multiple images?