# Capture camera image from Wolfram Cloud mobile app

Tags: wolfram-cloud, word-cloud, form-building

I want to deploy a Web API in the Wolfram Cloud that captures a camera image when called from the Wolfram Cloud mobile app. I started with the following minimal code example:

```
CloudDeploy[
  FormFunction[{"image"->"Image"}, #image&, "PNG"], CloudObject["Image Demo"]
]
```

When I open the API from the Wolfram Cloud mobile app, the photo gallery installed on my Android phone opens.

Is it possible to open and use the camera app instead to capture an image and pass the image to the API?

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105438/uploading-an-image-to-a-clouddeploy-wolfram-language-web-app?rq=1